# how to open different url in same IE Browser in other tab using autoit _IECreate exe file

Tags: internet-explorer, exe, autoit

I have created exe file using autoit _IECreate for open url in Internet Explorer,
Here is code I used.

```
1.
    #include <IE.au3>
    #include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

    Local $oIE = _IECreate("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login")
    ; Check @extended return value to see if attach was successful

    2.#include <IE.au3>
    #include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

    Local $oIE = _IECreate("https://login.salesforce.com")
```

for two url I have created 2 exe files, when I run exe opening in two different IE windows, My requirement is both url has to open in same IE in another tab.

Answer (score 0):

I could never get IE Create to open in tabs so I used a work around.

```
#include <Process.au3>

_RunDos("start http://www.autoitscript.com")
Sleep(3000)
_RunDos("start www.google.com")
```